# No access to partner

Tags: google-api, nest-device-access

I set up the Device Access Project with my G Suite email, which does not have a nest account (cause that is somehow forbidden). But when I log in with my regular gmail to nest and try to link that account to the PCM, it says: "No access to partner

Information could not be retrieved. Please contact [PROJECT NAME] to verify that your account has been properly set up. You may need to add the developer email address as a home member in the Google Home app settings."

My regular gmail has been declared as a high access owner on the GCP, so what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Might be two things going on here.

One, I don't think Workspace/GSuite accounts are fully supported for Device Access, because you can't set up Google Nest devices with them. So you might not be able to use Device Access with that anyway.

https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/7571892?hl=en

Two, for that error, you have to add the gmail account as a member of the structure prior to account linking:

https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/reference/errors/pcm#no_access_to_partner

Answer (score 0):

Hit this problem recently. Eventually figured out the cause of this problem: the Data Access project must not be created on a gSuite account. It has to be created on a gmail account. Meanwhile, the GCP project that supplies the consent page and OAuth2 client id can be created on a gSuite account or a gmail account. Hope this info is helpful.

Update: recreated a new gmail address with a GCP project and a Data Access project, suddenly it stopped working. Used gSuite account to create a GCP project. It still could not work with the Data Access project. Eventually found the solution at [the bottom of this Google Code Lab page](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/codelabs/web-app#1): "By default, a project is created in Sandbox mode. For Sandbox projects, the Google account you used to register Device Access Console must be the owner, or a member of the structure of the device you are going to control."